# How to put modal image to image insert from Wordpress content in a post?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

How to put a modal image to images in a post inserted throw **WordPress** when i create a post.

How can I control the image insert in the article and put custom **JavaScript** and **CSS** how can I do it for **WordPress** website??

[image: back-end pic]

[image: preview of the page]

but it cant access the content of wordpress

```
   $("#myModal .post_content img").each(function(){

    $("#myModal p").wrap('<div class="lightgallery"></div>');


    $(this).preprend('<a href="">
        <img data-sub-html="'.get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt.'" class="slider-image-fullscreen" data-src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postid,'full').'"  src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/Magnifier.png" style="position:absolute; height:25px; width:25px;">
        </a>');

});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fWU8.png)

Comment: That's something you could easily do by installing a WordPress plug-in

Comment: i had the same problem, and i solved, but i want know what method are u using (which modalbox or lightbox)

Comment: @TriForce - if you had the same method and solved it may be you should share it here and help solve her problem.

Comment: i am using light gallery ( lightbox)

Comment: i just wanted to know first the method hes using to modify my solution and post here, i will post soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, u need to detect images from wordpress first, i assume u have them in a container, so u need add an ID to the image container. (also u can use a class or anything, but u need identify the image container)

in the document ready u need use a code something like this:

```
//This is the container which contains the images inserted by wordpress
$("#lightgallery img").each(function(){ //search all images inside

    //get the imgs url
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src"); 

    //put the image inside a div
    $(this).wrap('<div class="myImage"></div>'); 

    //adds the button to launch the lightbox
    $(this).parent().prepend('<a href="'+imgSrc+'">View</a>'); 

    //adds the button to launch the lightbox (include thumbnail)
    //$(this).parent().prepend('<a href="'+imgSrc+'">View <img src="'+imgSrc+'"></a>'); 

});

//load gallery after images get converted to links
$("#lightgallery").lightGallery({ //this is the parent container of imgs
    selector:'a', //this is the button to launch the lightbox
    thumbnail:false //if u want use thumbs change it to true, so u need include an image inside the button container to get detected as thumb, in this case inside the "a", u can "uncomment" the hidden line above to try it
});
```

You can see the complete code i already made for u (including an example css).

Click here: https://jsfiddle.net/stptaj9h/23/

Note: Dont forget to include all lightbox libraries (js and css), in this case: lightgallery.css, lightgallery.js, lg-fullscreen.js and lg-thumbnail.js

Comment: but it cant access the content of wordpress

   $("#myModal .post_content img").each(function(){

        $("#myModal p").wrap('<div class="lightgallery"></div>');


        $(this).preprend('<a href="">
            <img data-sub-html="'.get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt.'" class="slider-image-fullscreen" data-src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postid,'full').'"  src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/Magnifier.png" style="position:absolute; height:25px; width:25px;">
            </a>');

    });

Comment: 1- you deleted the imgSrc variable,, is needed because you need to send the original image source to the link button. 2- youre not using wrap in the img, ure applying to modal p... thats wrong 3- you write prepRend instead prepend (dont double R). 4- you didnt added the .parent() before the prepend(). your code should to be something like this: http://pastebin.com/tNs7xhA8 remember to read my example: https://jsfiddle.net/stptaj9h/23/ dont add inline classes, just add them from css